# I have added my solution. can you tell me where i am making mistake in my sql query

Tags: sql

This is one of the problem from the leetcode.
https://leetcode.com/problems/investments-in-2016/description/
Write an SQL query to report the sum of all total investment values in 2016 tiv_2016, for all policyholders who:

have the same tiv_2015 value as one or more other policyholders, and
are not located in the same city like any other policyholder (i.e., the (lat, lon) attribute pairs must be unique).

My query:

```
WITH lattu AS (
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) AS lat_lon
  FROM insurance
  GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)
  HAVING COUNT(CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)) < 2
)

SELECT Round(sum(tiv_2016),2) as tiv_2016 
FROM insurance
WHERE CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) IN (SELECT lat_lon FROM lattu)
group by tiv_2015
HAVING COUNT(tiv_2015) > 1;
```

I am not getting correct output for this testcase
[image]
I have attach my output and the output i am expecting
[image]

Round tiv_2016 to two decimal places.
[image]
[image]

Comment: 'where am I making mistake' - if you get an error message please publish it in full. One mistake is tagging 3 rdbms - which one are you using and what version? another mistake is publishing table definitions as images rather than text.

Comment: I am using leetcode platform (mysql). I have added more details in the question. please let me know if anything else needed to be added.

Comment: I am unclear what the problem is see https://dbfiddle.uk/Jx3PBS1I which produces the expected output of 45..

Comment: I have attach one more testcase for which i am not getting the desired output/

Comment: I'm not going to transcribe all that and since it's not in the leetcode question please publish as text or to a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code - we need to identify values in tiv_2015 that appears more than once in the insurance table, the difference is that we now select lat_lon combinations that have a count of 1 (instead of less than 2) because we want the unique combinations; and, in the main query, we added an additional condition to filter policyholders with the same tiv_2015 value as other policyholders. After thatm we need to make sure that the policyholders are not located in the same city as any other, so we do CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) IN (SELECT lat_lon FROM lattu)

```
WITH lattu AS (
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) AS lat_lon
  FROM insurance
  GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)
  HAVING COUNT(CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)) < 2
)

SELECT Round(sum(tiv_2016),2) as tiv_2016 
FROM insurance
WHERE CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) IN (SELECT lat_lon FROM lattu)
group by tiv_2015
HAVING COUNT(tiv_2015) > 1;
```

here's the updated version that should pass, mark it as the answer if it does, cheers!

```
WITH lattu AS (
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) AS lat_lon
  FROM insurance
  GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)
  HAVING COUNT(CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon)) = 1
), tiv_comparison AS (
  SELECT tiv_2015
  FROM insurance
  GROUP BY tiv_2015
  HAVING COUNT(tiv_2015) > 1
)
SELECT ROUND(SUM(tiv_2016), 2) AS tiv_2016 
FROM insurance
WHERE tiv_2015 IN (SELECT tiv_2015 FROM tiv_comparison)
  AND CONCAT_WS('_', lat, lon) IN (SELECT lat_lon FROM lattu);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could prove this solution by publishing a fiddle..

Comment: Sure, here you go - https://dbfiddle.uk/XZpvQb_0

Answer (score 1):

You can find below the answer using SQL SERVER 2022.If you need additional information because you don't understand something, please ask me.

```
select sum(tiv_2016)as tiv_2016  from insurance i
where exists(select * from insurance where i.pid<>pid and i.tiv_2015=tiv_2015 )
AND pid in (
SELECT PID FROM insurance  
WHERE CONCAT (LAT, LON) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT (LAT, LON) FROM prob 
WHERE i.PID<>PID
)
);
```